# How to add a text in next column of CSV in bash script

Tags: bash, loops, sed, while-loop, paste

I have 2 files

```
#cat file.txt
aaa
bbb
ccc

#cat input.txt
191
112
339
```

I need

```
#cat output
aaa,191
bbb,112
ccc,339
```

I am trying

```
while IFS= read -r line
do

cat file.txt | grep "\.$line$" | wc -l >> output.txt
sed -i "1 i\\$line"  output.txt

done < input.txt
```

but it prints all lines each file in the group.

Any idea how can I archive my result?

Comment: If your actual files are same as shown samples then following may help you `paste -d',' file.txt input.txt`, let us know how it  goes then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are the type who prefers to write more lines rather than fewer lines you can try this:

```
echo -n "" > output.txt
while IFS= read -r line_input && IFS= read -r line_file <&3
  do
    echo "$line_input,$line_file" >> output.txt
done <input.txt 3<file.txt
```

if not, you can simple use @RavinderSingh13 hint ;-)

### Update

There was a comment regarding that the solution I supplied is slower then the solution

```
paste -d ',' file.txt input.txt
```

So I measured the execution time and I got the following values :

```
#!/bin/bash
START=$(date +%s.%N)

paste -d ',' file.txt input.txt > output.txt

END=$(date +%s.%N)
DIFF=$(echo "$END - $START" | bc)
echo "$DIFF";
```

I got the fastest :

> .004961322

```
| test 1 |.005088686   |  
| test 2 |.005036140   |  
| test 3 |.005019742   |  
| test 4 |.004961322   |  
| test 5 |.005030747   |  
| test 6 |.004978428   |
```

Next I checked the solution that I have supplied

```
#!/bin/bash
START=$(date +%s.%N)

echo -n "" > output.txt
while IFS= read -r line_input && IFS= read -r line_file <&3
  do
    echo "$line_input,$line_file" >> output.txt
done <input.txt 3<file.txt

END=$(date +%s.%N)
DIFF=$(echo "$END - $START" | bc)
echo "$DIFF";
```

And I got

> .002386748

```
| test 1 |.003516318   |  
| test 2 |.003538960   |  
| test 3 |.002386748   |  
| test 4 |.002584314   |  
| test 5 |.003461923   |  
| test 6 |.003619142   |
```

So my solution is just a bit longer, but it is faster then using `paste`.
The test was run on the same system.

Comment: The poster needs a preference, not only for writing more lines of code, but also for writing much slower, inefficient code. Sorry, but -1 for this solution, when the obviously much better one was already visible to all.

Comment: @mathguy my solution is based on the code the poster has supplied. I was aware that it is slower and longer, this is why I said ironically. I even mentioned the solution of RavinderSingh13. Stackoverflow's rule is clearly to use comments only for questions to supply solutions in the Answer Section. My Solution is working. Downgrade means it is a wrong solution. So please review your downgrade.

Comment: A downvote doesn't mean "wrong", it means "not helpful". If anyone is visiting this thread looking for a helpful approach to the problem, they should choose the other solution. If both solutions have only upvotes (worse: if for some reason the OP chose **your** inferior solution as the "correct answer"), how will the future visitor to the thread know what to choose? In my opinion, your answer is "not helpful" (it is not wrong!) - so the downvote.

Comment: @mathguy take a look at my edit. I made some measurements for you.

Comment: With small files, both measurements are bogus. Do it 1000 or 10000 times, or with bigger files. These numbers are both within a reasonable margin of error which could be affected by other things going on in the system - if a `cron` job fired at the same time that could bring up the load enough to completely dominate your measurement.

Comment: @tripleee I know it's damn hard to admit when you're wrong But I did a series of measurements (albeit briefly and with small files). You make guesses.

Comment: Your results definitely challenge my expectations, but I'm ready to be convinced; just not by your exposition so far. Can you update to cover the usual error sources (cache, too small sample resolution)?

Comment: My own experiment produces results in line with what I expected, and which seem to refute yours; https://ideone.com/NY7HuG. You can tweak the number of input lines and the number of times to repeat the test to get measurements at a reasonable level of granularity, though IdeOne will cap you at 15 seconds max run time. (I also include a tweaked version of yours which avoids the wasteful and inelegant reopening of the output file, though it won't matter much with `/dev/null`.)

Comment: For really small files, the overhead of the slow built-in `read` is apparently obscured by the increased efficiency of running purely built-in commands. Here's a demo with 5 lines of input: https://ideone.com/dLnFJd